# How to properly retrieve all data from an IndexedDb in a WinJS Windows 8 app?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, winjs, indexeddb

I've been googling for a while and have found nothing that can help me.
I'm just trying to retrieve all data from an IndexedDB.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("List", 1);
request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                db = request.result;
                console.log("success: " + db);
            };

request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
     db = event.target.result;
     var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("List", { keyPath: "id" });
     for (var i in parsedData) {
          objectStore.add(parsedData[i]);
     }

     console.log("RETRIEVING DATA");
     var transaction = request.transaction("List");
     var store = transaction.objectStore("List");
     store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (e) {
         var cursor = e.target.request;
         if (cursor) {
             console.log("List NAMES == " + cursor.value.Name);
         }
     }

}
```

Now, there's a couple things that need to be said about this code I have written. First of all, I'm aware that I retrieving information should be in a function of its own (I just wrote it this way for printing/logging purposes only). Second, for some reason, the "RETRIEVING DATA" should at least print to the log -- but it doesn't and I don't know why.
Third - and most importantly - I keep getting an error on this line:

```
var transaction = request.transaction("List");
```

The error is: `JavaScript runtime error: Function expected`

Not sure what is causing these 2 problems that I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The onupgradeneeded callback is only called when you increment the version parameter to indexedDB.open. You will need to increment, save, and then reload each time you want your example code to run. This should cause the RETRIEVING DATA command to be printed. It would be far easier to test if you did not try and insert/read data within the onupgradeneeded callback function. That way you would not need to increment the database version every time you wanted to test/run the code.
2. You need to open a transaction using the database object. Right now you state `var transaction = request.transaction('List');`. request is an IDBRequest. I don't think there is an IDBRequest.prototype.transaction method.  What you want to use is IDBDatabase.prototype.transaction. For example, `var transaction = db.transaction('List');`.
3. Alternatively to #2, but more complicated, you can use the implicit transaction that is used as part of onupgradeneeded. This is a special VERSION_CHANGE type transaction created automatically by indexedDB that is valid only within the body of the onupgradeneeded callback. VERSION_CHANGE txs support read/write. If you really want to do this, you could use `var transaction = event.target.transaction;`. I would not recommend this but it is possible.
4. In your cursor onsuccess callback, it looks like you are not advancing the cursor past the first record. You need to add `cursor.continue();` within the if block to continue the iteration.

A simple example of how to avoid having to upgrade the database each time:

```
function upgradeDatabase(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  db.createObjectStore('List', { keyPath: "id" });
}

function addParsedData(parsedData, callback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open('List', 1);
  request.onupgradeneeded = upgradeDatabase;
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction('List','readwrite');
    tx.oncomplete = callback;
    var list = tx.objectStore('List');
    for(var i in parsedData) {
      list.add(parsedData[i]);
    }
  };
}

function retrieve() {
  var request = indexedDB.open('List', 1);
  request.onupgradeneeded = upgradeDatabase;
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction('List');
    var list = tx.objectStore('List');
    var getAll = list.openCursor();
    var items = [];
    tx.oncomplete = function() {
      console.log('Got items %o', items);
    };
    getAll.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = event.target.result;
      if(!cursor) return;
      items.push(cursor.value);
      cursor.continue();
    };
  };
}

// This would connect, create, insert, and then select
addParsedData(parsedData, retrieve);
```

Comment: is there a way to auto increment the version of the database on its own? How or when do I manually change that 1 into a 2 or what ever?

Comment: Would I have to change the version each time I insert something new??

Comment: There is no way to auto increment that is built in to indexedDB. Nothing prevents you from using a localStorage hack. I would suggest using the patterns promoted by the developers of indexedDB instead, where you simply execute other requests without upgrading the database unless the schema changed. You do not need to change the version to insert something new.

Comment: the line "tx.oncomplete = callback;" -- in the addparsedData function -- What is the callback? I know what a call back function is, but I'm talking about the instance in your example, where is it declared?

Comment: the code in your example worked (for me) after I made a small fix: in the "getAll.onsuccess" function..... "var cursor = event.target.result" should be "var cursor = getAll.result || event.target.result". the cursor was coming out as undefined (again, for me) before making this fix. But regardless, it works -- thanks.

Comment: The callback is the second argument to the addParsedData function. It is just an example of how to split up where you write code. For example, if you want something to occur _after_ the inserts fully complete, then you would put this in a function, and pass in that function as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Within the body of `getAll.onsuccess = function(event) {...}`, the following are all the same exact thing: 'event.target', 'getAll', and 'this'. this is implicitly set as the bound context of the function. event.target is set to getAll when js creates the event object to pass to the function. getAll is simple the name of the request variable. It should be 100% identical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it isn't showing the console.log in your cause.
It doesn't work for me with the code above because I don't have the stuff for parsedData, when I comment that out I get log and the error you are giving on the transaction.

That error is because you shouldn't call it is a function. It is already an open transaction and you can just do this: `request.transaction.objectStore("<Objectstore>");` for opening a store.

So this probably doesn't fix the console.log issue you are having but it should fix the other part!

Comment: the parsed Data is just a JSON object.

Comment: So I have request.transaction.objectore('List'); -- I finally get the "retrieving data" log -- but I don't get the log in the if statement to print the values.